# Visual Studio 2013 Premium on windows 7 doesnt have Javascript as a project template

Tags: javascript, templates, project, visual-studio-2013

I try to create a JavaScript project VS2013, but no matter what, I don't see the JavaScript project type in the templates.
I can create a javascript file and edit it with full support, but just don't have the javascript project as a selection option.

Any suggestions:

VS 2013 Premium on Windows 7 Professional

Comment: There is no JS project template.  Create a web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the main idea of Javascript apps in Visual Studio 2013 is to develop Windows Store apps, therefore a js project template on VS2013 is only possible with Win8 machines. However, you can download [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/web-pages), and it gives you JS project templates. And then you can port them to Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

This screenshot is from my Win7 machine.